# What is the pass / fail ratio accepted ? when we execute Automation Selenium Tests only once NO re execution

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, webdriver

What is the pass / fail ratio accepted ?

when we execute Automation Selenium Tests 100 test only once and we are not re executing again.

80 Passed / 20 Failed (No application issue failures)

was my automation selenium script / code stable and effective ?

Note: 
each test may run for 3 mins.

Comment: As these are functional tests, I would say anything bellow `90-95%` is not to be trusted. (e.g.: when I run my regression, if any run goes bellow that threshold, I get a Tweelio message from the automation harness to warn me). 

The `80%` you informed us about, it not acceptable IMHO. Btw, if there were no **"application issue failures"**, then why were so many failing?

Comment: There's no straight answer to this question. The threshold should be related to the criticity of each test and to the level of quality that you are trying to reach. Testing is about addressing the risks of failing to provide a service/feature to a customer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass/Fail ratio varies from project to project and functional test case.

If test case having major impact and that is within failed test case then that ratio does not have any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

IMO if you have 100 test cases only 4-5 can be flaky.